# Quick way to select by attribute and zoom to selection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, select, zoom

I need to visually control hundreds of points in a layer on top of aerial photographs. Using the attribute table, selecting (with column filter expression) and zooming manually is cumbersome - so I plugged together a processing script which has the layer and the field, in which I'd like to search, hardcoded to the script..

That script helps - however, It would be much more handy to have a dockwidget in which I could put the search strings, without having to open the algorithm dialog each time I want to search a feature..

**Can I put this script to a dockable widget without making a plugin?**

Or maybe there are other methods (maybe built in or by available plugins) to quickly search values repeatedly in a field of a layer?

Another idea would be to assign a shortcut to the processing script and thus save me from having to start the algorithm by clicking it in the processing toolbox - but I don't know if this is possible..

```
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from qgis.core import *
    from qgis.utils import *

    #====================================
    ##[User scripts]=group
    ##input_str=string
    #====================================

    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    allLayers = canvas.layers()
    n = len(allLayers)
    for i in range(0, n):
        if allLayers[i].name() == 'waypoints':
            break
    tarL = allLayers[i]

    # Get a featureIterator from an expression:

    expr = QgsExpression( "\"name\"='" + input_str + "'" )
    it = tarL.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )

    # Build a list of feature Ids from the result obtained above
    ids = [j.id() for j in it]

    # Select features with the ids obtained
    tarL.setSelectedFeatures( ids )

    # Zoom to selected features:
    canvas.zoomToSelected()
```